# wp_get_shortlink() only producing one link?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to add buttons to a Wordpress template that links to a specific post's shortlink.

My code *was* working, but suddenly is not. It used to link to each post's specific page. Now it is only linking to one post (i.e I click on Grilled Chicken post and it links me to Mushroom Stir-fry).

I can't find out what's wrong... Like I said, this was working. It is OUTSIDE of Wordpress's loop. This code adds the link: "...echo wp_get_shortlink(); ..."

JQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var logosToInsert = "<div class='button-logos' style='margin-bottom: 25px;'><img width=75 src='http://dev.mylifedish.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/cutlogo1.jpg'/><img width=75 src='http://dev.mylifedish.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/potcooklogo.jpg'/>";

var htmlToInsert = '<div class="buttons"><div class="button-wrap"><a href=<?php echo wp_get_shortlink(); ?>><button style="width: 100%;" class="button small secondary" type="button"><span class="btn-text">Download</span></button></a></div><div class="button-wrap"><a href=<?php echo wp_get_shortlink(); ?>><button style="width: 100%;" class="button small secondary" type="button"><span class="btn-text">Read More</span></button></a></div></div>';

 $('.entry-content').wrapInner("<div class='row'></div>");
 $('.button-wrap').wrapInner("<div class='row'></div>");
 $('.entry-image img').addClass('col-xs-12 col-sm-6');
 $('.entry-image img').css('padding', '0');
 $('.entry-content p').addClass('col-xs-6 col-sm-6');

 //$('.entry-content').append(logosToInsert);
 $('.entry-content').append(htmlToInsert);
 });

 </script>
```

Comment: If you are outside of the Loop, how can WordPress guess the ID of the post you want the shortlink?

Comment: It was working though. that's why I'm confused

Comment: Are you sure you didn't change anything? Without an ID as an argument, you need to be in the Loop. Also, it won't solve your problem, but you should encapsulate the value of `href` into quotes.